# for loop in Pig Latin

Tags: python

I'm building a Pig Latin programme.
First, I need define VOWELS in a list which is:

```
vowel = ['a','e','i','o','u']
```

However the requirement for my homework says I need a infinite loop ). and when type 'exit', the programme stops.

Also, I need to use the list when in the conversion part(Hint: `for x in VOWELS`)

So, how do I use this for loop?

If I use `if` statement, it works fine.

```
while text!=('exit'):
    ltext = text.lower()
    first_letter = word[0]
    if first_letter in vowel:
        new_word=ltext+'ay'
    else:
        new_word=ltext[1:]+first_letter+'ay'
    print(new_word)
```

But I don't know how to use a `for` loop. So how do I use a `for` loop to compare the `first_letter in vowel`?

Comment: Accidentally hit delete whoops.  Treat your string as just a list of characters.  Use that in a for loop.  That should give you a push in the right direction without us doing your homework

Comment: This isn't typical Pig Latin.  In general, you remove the letters before the first vowel, tack them to the end of the word, and add "ay", but that's not what you're doing.  Clarify, please?

Comment: Please clarify your need for a **for** loop.  For what you've shown us, a **for** loop would be silly: you are correct to use the **in** operator.  What do you mean by the "convention part"?  This isn't a typical programming concept.

Comment: @Prune sry for the typo, the list of VOWELS need to be used in the conversion process.

Comment: You still haven't clarified the need for the **for** loop, or why you're using this strange conversion.  For instance, this would change the input "trash" into "trashay" (should be "ashtray"), and "easy" would turn into "asyeay".  I sthis really what you're trying to do?  A conventional conversion *would* use a for loop, but to iterate through the letters of the word, not the vowels.

Answer (score 1):

To change the **while** loop into an infinite loop, perhaps you're supposed to use the following?

```
while True:
    text = input("Enter something")
    if text == "exit":
        break
```

Note that both iteration and **in** work just as well on a string as on a list:

```
vowel = "aeiou"
...
if first_letter in vowel:
    ...
```

I'll update this concerning that **for** loop when you explain the need more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I use a for loop to compare the `first_letter` in vowel?

For loops are used to iterate over a sequence, for example a word which is a sequence of characters. So, if you want to iterate over a word say, you can do something like this.

```
word = "stackoverflow"
for charcter in word:
    print(charcter)
```

If you want to iterate over all the words of a sentence, you can do something like this.

```
sentence = "Welcome to stackoverflow, my friend"
for word in sentence.split():
    print(word)
```

[sentence.split()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm) - splits the sentence into words based on whitespaces.

---

For [Pig Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig_Latin), I believe you need something like this.

```
vowel = ['a','e','i','o','u']
while True: # infinite loop
    text = input("Give your input text: ")
    if text == "exit":
        break  # stops the loop
    else:
        if text[0].lower() in vowel:
            text = text + 'ay'
        else:
            if text[0].isupper():
                text = text[1].upper() + text[2:] + text[0].lower() + 'ay'
            else:
                text = text[1:] + text[0] + 'ay'
        print(text)
```

Sample I/O:

```
Give your input text: pig
igpay
Give your input text: Latin
Atinlay
Give your input text: exit
```

Comment: @user7607794 did my answer help you? if yes, you can accept it as the answer!